# Is this LESS syntax invalid and if so how can I fix it?

Tags: css, less

I have the following:

```
> li {
   float:left;
}
> li:active, 
> li.current {
   background-color:#888888;
}
> li:hover {
   background-color:#e9e9e9;
```

When I am using Mindscape web workbench it tells me that the line "> li: active" has invalid syntax.  If I remove the following line it's okay. If I remove that line it's okay. So is my syntax really wrong?

Comment: what you are making? is li having links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the active property works with the "li" you should use instead something like:

```
li a:active
```